# controlling a java program from another java program on another node

Tags: java, swing, networking

I've never been doing this kind of work in java before.

the requirements are :

there will be atleast 2 PCs connected in the same LAN network.
each has a Java Desktop Program Running on it.

let say PC#1 has Java1 app on it, and PC#2 will have Java2 app on it.

- Java2 on PC#2 will be able to find another node/PC ( by provided IP/hostname ) and will able to connect to Java1 on PC#1.
- Java1 on PC#1 will be able to give permission for Java2 to connect to itself and take control of any swing items available in Java1 app.
- Java1 app will have a jButton and a jLabel, this what the button does :

  ```
  private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
          /* labelNum has been declared out of this function and has "0" 
          as it's initial text value */                          
          int num = Integer.parseInt(labelNum.getText());
          num ++;
          labelNum.setText(String.valueOf(num));
  }
  ```

while Java2 only has a jButton on it, when connected to Java1 on PC#1, jButton on Java2 will do the same function as the jButton on Java1 app does, it will increment the value of labelNum on Java1 App.

I am completely dont have any idea on how to do this, I normally search the entire internt for possible answer, asking here is my last finale desperate resort.

Thnks for your time.
( and pls pardon my maybe inappropriate english ).

Note :
I've posted the similar question on CodeRanch, but after 12hours I think I can get more help here, if I got / provided with an answer on any of the site, I will post / update the answer on both and close both post.

Thank you.

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how and what to ask here. Your question is way too broad. Answering it would require to sit down with you and spend hours explaining all the different aspects of your requirements. That is not what this community is meant for.

Comment: Having said that: you have to first learn about Java networking, sockets and such.

Comment: Next you have to define some sort of protocol so that the two sides have a defined way of talking to each other. I would also suggest to not control ui elements. Rather define "commands" of some sort that trigger specific activity. Of course, locally a swing button can also invoke such a command. And read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question please

Comment: that's what mostly I found when searching about this topic, but haven't been able to find a quite similar implementation of socket tech to my need, most of em are about creating network messenger java app, so I thought that I could maybe recieve that specific example of implementation here, and yes Now I am also start reading about java networking and sockets, so thnks also for the clue of what to learn.

Comment: Use Java sockets and send command between apps

Comment: @GhostCat, I am reading that link now, I really appreaciate the help and suggestions, Thnks.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of these applications? And I agree with that answer: you are (easily!) looking at one week of full-time work, for a newbie, even more. I really suggest that you identify a real person with some experience to sit down with you and work on this. This problem really looks too challenging for a newbie to solve via internet help alone.

Comment: @GhostCat I am trying to create a simple App for Queue Management in java, so this feature meant to be used in the Locket's PC where the user press a jButton to call the next number in the queue while updating the main Display which was displayed by separate java program on another computer.

I would prefer that way also, but too bad not so many people with that depth of knowledge on java desktop programming here, mostly here people do it in vb.net, and I am not.

Comment: haven;t been able to came across any specific tuts or explanation to do this in java on the internet, so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have completed the Program that I needed using the Java Socket Programming, all work perfectly fine and as it should be, and way less tricky compared to RMI and it's security manager problems that I faced.

I used use String Tokenizer to tokenize the String sent by the Client PC to extract info such as ( clientNo commandType  queueType currentQueueNo ) separated by space.

clientNo = the Number ID of the Client sending the request to the server
commandType = the Type of the Command/Function requested to be executed by the client.
queueType = the Type of the Queue requested by the client
currentQueueNo = the Current / Last Queue Number served by the Client

using if function, server PC will know which method need to be executed and then echoes back an answer in form of a String to the Client, then Client will set the Answer as the new text value of the Label.

I also used Multithreading, so that multiple Clients can connect to the Socket Server PC without blocking each other.

and I log all of the processes done in a jTextArea, so user or admin will keep updated about the interaction between the server pc and the clients.

hope it clear enough as an aswer.

Comment: You should improve your answer. SO aims to collect high quality answers that can be useful to the community and this kind of answer does not help. You can look at [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to try to improve your answer.

Comment: Thnks, I'll try,

Answer (score 0):

This belongs to a much bigger problem on how to send / receive requests from another node, which - believe me or not - takes a lot more work than 1 or 2 programs. If you took the scale down to 2 MCUs with 2 SD cards or whatever, it would be a lot easier. That should be your start

Comment: Mcu? SD cards? How does that help here? We have no idea about the actual problem to be solved here, so that part of your answer is pure guessing.

Comment: really ? I thought this kind of problem could be done either with Socket or RMI in java ? I am still learning about both, though.

Answer (score 0):

here are the steps.

- learn socket programming
- send message from pc#2 to pc#1 on clicking the button
- get the message on pc#1, if its the same message you sent from pc#2 then increment the current integer value of label.

Comment: as my Answer, I already finished the software using indeed Socket Programming.